# NetLify CMS - gulpe server error due to missing ./bin/hugo.win32 file

Tags: gulp, netlify

I am testing NetLify CMS for a project, but I am not able to work in my local environment, because gulp server crashs before it start, due to the error below:

```
$ npm start

> victor-hugo@1.0.0 start C:\Users\maufa\Documents\web-development\kaldi-hugo-cms-template
> gulp server

[14:17:07] Requiring external module babel-register
[14:17:08] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\web-development\kaldi-hugo-cms-template\gulpfile.babel.js
[14:17:08] Starting 'hugo'...
[14:17:08] Starting 'css'...
[14:17:09] Starting 'js'...
[14:17:09] Starting 'svg'...
[14:17:09] Starting 'cms'...
[14:17:09] Finished 'cms' after 150 ms
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn ./bin/hugo.win32 ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! victor-hugo@1.0.0 start: `gulp server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the victor-hugo@1.0.0 start script 'gulp server'.
```

So, looks like it is trying to find hugo.win32 inside the bin folder. 
However, inside this folder I ave:

- hugo.darwin
- hugo.exe
- hugo.linux

Any clue?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this issue is particular to the [Kaldi Hugo template](https://github.com/netlify-templates/kaldi-hugo-cms-template). I installed on Windows and got the same error, then I tried renaming `hugo.exe` to `hugo.win32`, and it worked. I found the error in `gulpfile.babel.js` (incorrect string identifier for Windows), and submitted a PR. If you don't want to wait for the merge, feel free to change your version directly: https://github.com/netlify-templates/kaldi-hugo-cms-template/pull/3/files